# Name current software/online services for HIGH-QUALITY text-to-speech (TTS) in German

Tags: software

There are alot free, shareware, open source, proprietary programs/apps & online services with bad - medium (IMHO, often sounds robotic and not spoken fluently) quality. Esp. the quality differences for different languages are high. Some german sites offer already "news reader button", but imho no HAL (2001 Space Odyssey) quality ;)

Maybe some here own licences of more expensive or tested occupationally several TTS programs. Whats your best buy/download tip for German?

**Please name only good-high quality software (no robotic voice, fluent reading)**

**Please give at least a link to software, runnnig platforms/OS, rough price.**

<sub>PS: @ mods, i made 2 questions as speech recognition and synthesis are fundamental different and most software focuses only on one of both, same as in music synthesizer & analysis software (e.g. Melodyne high quality music analysis software without any synthesis capabilites)</sub>

Comment: I *still* think this would have been better as a single question.

Comment: **Text to speech readers** are different to **text recognition**. I think it's a good idea to have them in a separate question.

Comment: @Takkat: I know that they are technically quite different, but they are related enough to be discussed usefully in a single question.

Comment: the problem with one question is besides loosing overview what TTS & recognition software is: how can other vote for a software recommended in an answer that they would recommmend too. The state of the art and leading companies for speech recognition and synthesis are not the same, as the algorithms are fundamental different. I really want people here to vote for the best high-quality software for German. **So a answer should recommend ONE software, so this gets basically a poll**

Comment: The drawback is getting common discusson (such as the one currently happening) duplicated ;-) I don't agree with you, but I don't feel strong enough about it to keep arguing ;-) (And if it's supposed to be a poll, then you should make it a community wiki).

Comment: I think it should be  a CW question.